# Kubernetes pod created through Airflow remains in running state

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I've set up Airflow in a Kubernetes cluster. To run tasks, I'm using the `KubernetesPodOperator`.

When I run a task and take a look at `kubectl get pods`, I see a pod is created correctly and it also completes. However, when I look at Airflow, I see the state isn't updated and it says it's still in the running state.

```
[2019-01-27 12:43:56,580] {models.py:1595} INFO - Executing <Task(KubernetesPodOperator): xxx> on 2019-01-20T00:00:00+00:00
[2019-01-27 12:43:56,581] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run xxx xxx 2019-01-20T00:00:00+00:00 --job_id 15 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/xxx.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmpxx39wldz']
[2019-01-27 12:45:21,603] {models.py:1355} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: xxx.xxx 2019-01-20T00:00:00+00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance Not Already Running' FAILED: Task is already running, it started on 2019-01-27 12:43:56.565328+00:00.
[2019-01-27 12:45:21,639] {models.py:1355} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: xxx.xxx 2019-01-20T00:00:00+00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'running' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
[2019-01-27 12:45:21,641] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-01-27 12:45:21,641] {jobs.py:2614} INFO - Task is not able to be run
```

Is there anything specific I should do to return the pod's state back to Airflow? The `KubernetesPodOperator` is defined as follows:

```py
do_something = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='xxx',
    image='gcr.io/project/image',
    namespace='default',
    name='xxx',
    arguments=['dummy'],
    xcom_push=True,
    in_cluster=True,
    image_pull_policy='Always',
    trigger_rule='dummy',
    dag=dag,
)
```

**Edit:** It appears that the base container has completed, but `airflow-xcom-sidecar` is still running. Is there anything specific I should do to stop that one?

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem? I'm encountering the same issue and I can't find the root cause as of why the sidecar keeps running. `/airflow/xcom/return.json` has properly been created and the base container has completed.

Comment: I think I ended up changing part of the set up. So, in your case, is everything successful, but it doesn't show up in the Airflow XCom?

Comment: My problem seems to be exactly the same issue that you had. The base container terminates successfully (pod is marked as `completed`) but the sidecar container keeps running. If I ssh into the sidecar container, I can see that the `return.json` file has been created by the base container, which means the issue is not that the sidecar keeps looking for it or something. And I have the same error message on Airflow (`...dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED...`).

Comment: The exact same setup sometimes works, it seems it might be caused by very long tasks. Truth is, Airflow running on top of k8s is unstable, I keep having problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly without looking at your setup, but it looks like the pod is done and it's trying to an [xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms) push to your main Airflow and it's not able to connect. I would check the logs for `airflow-xcom-sidecar`. Something like:

```
$ kubectl logs <airflow-job-pod> -c airflow-xcom-sidecar
```

You can also try running your `KubernetesOperator` with `xcom_push=False`:

```
do_something = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='xxx',
    image='gcr.io/project/image',
    namespace='default',
    name='xxx',
    arguments=['dummy'],
    xcom_push=False,
    in_cluster=True,
    image_pull_policy='Always',
    trigger_rule='dummy',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Oddly enough, those logs don't show anything. I'm currently working on a solution where I'm disabling the `xcom_push`, but can't update you on that one yet. Either way, I think `xcom_push` shouldn't prevent the solution from working.